# html - javascript not working in dynamic generated html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

A table row in a form which is dynamically generated with a "Add row " button.

One field in the row is Date which uses datepicker to select the date.

**PROBLEM:**

The datepicker doesn't show when the row is dynamically generated.

I am using bootstrap 3.

Here is the code that generate table row on button click.

```
    function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 40){                            // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }else{
        alert("Maximum Players per Entry is 40");

    }
}
```

**HTML MARKUP FOR DATE INPUT:**

```
     <div class="form-group">
 <label for="InputDatePicker">Date:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Date" id="InputDatePicker">
 </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT to call datepicker function on input**

```
<script>
$('#InputDatePicker').datepicker();
</script>
```

**UPDATED CODE TO ADD A NEW ROW AND INITIALIZING THE DATEPICKER**

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 40){                            // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
        $('#InputDatePicker').datepicker();
    }else{
        alert("Maximum Players per Entry is 40");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you mean that you're using [the jQuery UI Datepicker plugin](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)?  (Or something similar?)  In that case you're never initializing the plugin on the dynamically added elements:

```
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
}
```

It sounds like you're successfully adding new elements to the page.  But once those elements are added, you need to target the one(s) that should be a Datepicker and initialize the plugin on those elements:

```
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
}
$(someSelector).datepicker();
```

The value of `someSelector` is entirely up to you, I don't know your markup.  But the idea is that you need to uniquely identify the newly added elements which need to become Datepickers.  Initializing the plugin when the page loads only initializes the elements which exist at that time, not elements which are added later.

---

**Update:**

According to your jQuery selector:

```
$('#InputDatePicker').datepicker();
```

You are identifying an element with an `id` of "InputDatePicker".  So one of two things is happening:

1. Your newly-added elements don't have that `id`, which means this selector isn't selecting them.  In this case you need to select the newly-added elements.
2. Your newly-added elements *do* have that `id`, which means your HTML is invalid and the behavior of the code is undefined.  In this case you need to fix your HTML so that you don't re-use `id` values and update your selector accordingly.  `id` values need to be unique, by definition.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I have added the relevant information that was missing in my question, 
the way you asked to initialize the plugin is not working, Please have a look again and might you can help now. Thanks

Comment: @Abrar: Did you attempt my suggestion?  According to your updated code in the question, you did not.  That `script` block is only going to be executed *once* when the page loads.  Your `addRow` function is being called later, after that `script` block has already been executed.  So you need to initialize the Datepicker plugin *again* on the newly added elements.  jQuery has no way of initializing elements which *don't exist yet*.

Comment: yes I tried your suggestion by adding the    
        $('#InputDatePicker').datepicker();
after the for loop but it didn't worked.

Comment: @Abrar: Can you update the question to show the updated code?  Also, elaborate on *how* it's not working.  Is the jQuery selector finding the elements you expect it to?

Comment: Sure I added the updated code, Sorry I don't know the answer to your second question.

Comment: @Abrar: I've updated my answer accordingly.  In short, your jQuery selector isn't able to find the newly-added elements either because it's incorrect or because your HTML is invalid.

Comment: Also add the row undynamically. Put into page HTML and see if it works that way with the date picker. Narrow down the source of the problem. At the moment it could be JavaScript, jquery, html even a conflict with bootstrap or other code.